# terraform enterprise smtp disable cert validation

Tags: terraform-enterprise

How can we disable smtp cert validation in TFE? I see in their documentation that

```
Note: The SMTP server used with Terraform Enterprise must support connection via SSL with a valid certificate and STARTTLS secure communication; SMTPS is not supported in Terraform Enterprise.
```